# python basic: how to sort a list only by considering the number?

Tags: python, sorting

I admit I dont know how to give this question a better title. :-( Anybody has a better idea for the title?

Here is my problem:

I want to sort this list:

```
a = ['at10', 'at11', 'at12', 'at13', 'at9', 'at1', 'at8']
```

Every item from the list begins with two letters and has some numbers.

The desired result is as followings. The list is sorted by numbers.

```
['at1', 'at8', 'at9', 'at10', 'at11', 'at12', 'at13']
```

I tried with `sorted(a)` and many of its `key` settings. But I could not get the result. Anybody please help me out? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use the `sort` method: `a.sort(key = lambda i: int(i[2:]))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sorted(a, key=lambda x:int(x[2:]))
#['at1', 'at8', 'at9', 'at10', 'at11', 'at12', 'at13']
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your data has a pattern (from index 2 above is a number), you can get each number by defining like `getnum` (this is one way) function below.

After this, you can use the `sorted` function in terms of those values (sort by the numbers in the string).

```
a = ['at10', 'at11', 'at12', 'at13', 'at9', 'at1', 'at8']

def getnum(s):
    num = int(s[2:]);
    return num

b=sorted(a, key = getnum)
print(b)
```